# Wordpress html5blank theme - Media Queries not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the html5blank to create a site on WordPress. Locally, the media queries are working perfectly fine but when and I add them to the wordpress style.css file, they don't seem to work. I have got rid of all media queries and kept only a simple one just to test it and it's still not working. I have my media queries at the end.

This is part of my header.php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">    

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

    <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/style.css" />
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script>
    // conditionizr.com
    // configure environment tests
    conditionizr.config({
        assets: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>',
        tests: {}
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<header>
```

These are the simple media queries I added for testing in Wordpress to the bottom of the css file, but are not working:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  div.balancepersonal {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.balancepersonal {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

This is the p tag in the index.php file I'm trying to make responsive:

```
<div class="balance-personal">
        <div class="balance-container"> 

            <div class="top-div-balance">
                <img src="img/IMG_6739.jpg" class="trees-photo">
                <div class="trees-shadow">
                    <div class="container amenidades-txt">
                    <p class="balancepersonal">BALANCE PERSONAL</p>
```

Comment: try `max-width: 590px` it should be different than your other media query

Comment: @Sohrab, I've tried all kind of combinations, such as ... (max-width: 1400px) and (min-width: 1200px) ... but it's just that media queries are not working in wordpress.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz the media queries are being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `stylesheet_url` param for bloginfo as seen here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/

Reason: your current param gives location on the server file directory as opposed to a web location a browser can access.

Edit `stylesheet_url` should give you the complete location to your `style.css`.

Alternatively you could use the `template_directory_uri` (as you are elsewhere) and add the `style.css` part

Comment: no, no 404 errors in the browser for the style.css file